# Do outputs declared in output and reg both have to have number of bits?

Tags: verilog

Are these two lines of code in verilog the same?

1. output[1:0] r;

   reg[1:0] r;
2. output[1:0] r;

   reg r;

Do the number of bits have to be declared twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. No No.

Verilog offers a few styles of declaring ports. The recommend way is known as ANSI-style, where you only mention the port name once.

```
module m(output reg [1:0] r, input clk);
```

It unfortunate that this style does not appear first in the LRM.
And, yes using the style in your question requires that the bit widths match.